# supplying @Query with a runtime generated jpql query

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql

I am working with a method that generates a query string according to a set of filters that the user wants to apply when retrieving data from the database. So for each new filter, the method appends something like `AND variable_x = '4'` for example.

I want to use the `JpaRepository` interface of spring data and I want to make a method that is annotated with `@Query` to be able to execute this generated query. However, the `@Query` requires a constant as a value. So is there a way to have the `@Query` execute this generated query? Could something like this work for example? Can I give the entire JPQL query as a parameter to `@Query`?

```
@Query("?1")
public abstract void executeRuntimeGeneratedQuery(String query);
```

Or are there more elegant solutions that solve my problem?

Comment: You will have to use QueryDSL or Specifications for use with Spring Data with conditions. Check this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) or [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) for how to 
 do that. For simpler conditions you could use [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I give the entire JPQL query as a parameter to `@Query`?

No this is not possible. `@Query` annotations are a static thing and you can use parameters (including SpEL expressions) only as supported by JPA which basically means expressions, not column or table names and certainly not complete statements.

> Or are there more elegant solutions that solve my problem?

Yes, there are alternatives. From what you describe [Specifications seem to fit the bill best](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).

Of course, you can combine that with [custom methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) which will also save the day if you want to do more than Specifications can offer.

Comment: the specifications example contains a serious error 

LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2); isen't possible. It should be LocalDate.now().minusYears(2) I believe because localdate has a private constructor. But thanks for the links.